# Finding eigenvalues of the Laplacian on solenoidal (divergence-free) vector fields

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

In Mathematica it is easy to find eigenvalues of the Laplacian in simple cases.  For example, on $\Omega\in \mathbb{R}^2$:

```
{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 6]
```

But is it possible to restrict the abovementioned problem to solenoidal (divergence-free) vector fields? That is, how could I numerically find $(u, \lambda)$, such that:

$-\Delta  u=\lambda u\\
\nabla\cdot u=0$

With Dirichlet boundary conditions on $\partial \Omega$ and $u=u(x,y)$, $(x,y)\in \Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure that you do not mean the **Stokes eigenvalue problem** $-\Delta u + \operatorname{grad} p  = \lambda u$, $\operatorname{div} u = 0$ with $\int p(x) \, \mathrm{d} x =0$?

Comment: See also [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10492-006-0006-x.pdf) for an ansatz that utilizes a stream function $\psi$ with $u = \operatorname{curl} \psi$ to recast the eigenvalue problem into an eigenvalue problem for the bi-Laplacian. However, if I am not mistaken, this works only in simply-connected domains.

Answer (score 3):

*This is not really an answer, but may help to find a solution.*

## Iterative approach

What might work is solving the Stokes eigenvalue problem

$$- P \, A \, P \, v = \lambda \, P \, M \, P\, v$$

with the naive projector $P = I - B^T\, (B B^T)^{-1} \, B$ onto $\operatorname{ker}(B)$. Here $A$ is the stiffness matrix, $M$ is the mass matrix, and $B$ is the finite-element discretization of $\operatorname{div}$, all with respect a suitable (stable!) finite element discretization.
Then $u = P \, v$ should be what you are looking for.

The matrix $B^T\, (B B^T)^{-1} \, B$ is dense, so I would not recommend to assemble it; instead, only its action should be implemented in a matrix-free way (by exploiting a sparse $LU$-factorization of $B B^T$). While the matrices $M$, $A$, $B$ might be obtainable from *Mathematica*, *Mathematica*'s Arnoldi method does (as far as I know) not support matrix-free methods. Also one certainly wants to use a good preconditioner (e.g., geometric multigrid), which is also not available out of the box. (Notice that we cannot use ILU-preconditioner due to the absence of any concrete matrix.)

## Alternate approach

Alternatively, one could study the generalized eigenvalue problem
$$
\begin{pmatrix} A &B^T\\ B &0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} u \\ p \end{pmatrix}
=
\lambda \,
\begin{pmatrix} M &0\\ 0 & \varepsilon \, I \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} u \\ p \end{pmatrix}
$$
with some small $\varepsilon>0$.

That could be set up by

```
\[Epsilon] = 10^-12;
AA = ArrayFlatten[{{A, B\[Transpose]}, {B, 0.}}];
MM = ArrayFlatten[{{M, 0. B\[Transpose]}, {0. B, \[Epsilon] IdentityMatrix[Length[B],SparseArray, WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision]}}];
```

and solved with

```
{\[CapitalLambda], U} = Eigensystem[{AA, MM}, -6, Method -> "Arnoldi"];
```

A positive $\varepsilon$ is necessary, otherwise, the Arnoldi solver will complain. But don't ask me how stable or how accurate this might be in practice.

Comment: Henrik, thank you for the detailed answer! I've checked the article you mentioned - it is rather useful. I'm new to numerical methods and now I see that the problem is not so simple as I expected.